# Vector polynomial

Tags: polynomials, vectors

Let
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$
There exist constants $p$, $q$, and $r$ such that
$A^3 + pA^2 + qA + rI = 0$ where $I$ and $0$ are the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix and zero matrix, respectively. Find $p + q + r$.

Comment: Hint: compute the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: That would be the characteristic polynomial $p(x)=\det(xI-A)$, and you're looking for $p(1)-1=\det(I-A)-1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\det\left( A-\lambda I\right)=-\lambda ^3+6 \lambda +4$

Considering $P(\lambda)=\lambda ^3-6 \lambda -4$ we have

$P(A)=A^3-6A-4=$
$$=\left(
\begin{array}{lll}
 4 & 6 & 12 \\
 6 & 4 & 6 \\
 12 & 6 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)-6\left(
\begin{array}{lll}
 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)-4\left(
\begin{array}{lll}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{lll}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
So the sum of $p+q+r=-10$